# C compiler confusion

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

okay so I'm on OS and I use terminal to compile my c code. Whenever I make a file using nano or vim called "tst.c" (or whatever the name might be ) then I compile using (my teacher told me to use this everytime so I don't think this is the problem:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o tst.c ./tst.c
```

then it turns into binary I'm guessing. But when  I try to edit it again, it has all these weird encryptions I'm guessing like:

```
��������H���__PAGEZERO��������������������������������������������������������ÿ��__TEXT����������������������������������������������������__text����������__TEXT����������`�����*�������`���������������Ä������������__stubs���������__TEXT����������ä������������ä��������������Ä�����������__stub_helper���__TEXT����������ê������������ê���������������Ä������������__cstring�������
```

So, question is, how do I revert so I can edit and not make a new file every time???????

Comment: `-o tot.c` makes it the output file. Try `-o blah` instead. Always read documentation of tools you are using. Especially when they don't work as you expect. And if it is really how your teacher told you to do, then tell him that his suggestion have erased your work and you are not submitting it :P

Comment: don't call it *.c

`gcc -o DESTINATIONFILE SOURCEFILE` 
`gcc -o tot tot.c`

then open `./tot`

You basically overwrote your source code with its compiled binary

You need to rewrite that code to compile it again using my instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your original source file with the compiled executable because of the `-o` option:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o tst.c ./tst.c
                   ^^^^^^^^
```

You'll need to specify a different output file name in the `-o` option:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o tst tst.c
```

Otherwise, you can leave the `-o` option off entirely, and the compiled executable will be written to a file named `a.out`.

Eventually, you'll want to automate all of this with the [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) utility, but for now just be aware of how the `-o` option works.

Answer (score 0):

the -o (name) flag means you are storing the output into whatever you used for name.. so if you add .c to the end of the name you'll see lots of interesting stuff. Man pages are pretty awesome when learning about what each flags do.